# What do these metrics mean for Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

```
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {
    ......
    override def onQueryProgress(queryProgress: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
        println("Query made progress: " + queryProgress.progress)
    }
    ......
})
```

When StreamingQueryListener is added to Spark Structured Streaming session and output the queryProgress continuously, one of the metrics you will get is **durationMs**:

```
Query made progress: {
  ......
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 159136,
    "getBatch" : 0,
    "getEndOffset" : 0,
    "queryPlanning" : 38,
    "setOffsetRange" : 14,
    "triggerExecution" : 159518,
    "walCommit" : 182
  }
  ......
}​
```

Can anyone told me what do those sub-metrics in durationMs meaning in spark context? For example, what is the meaning of "addBatch 159136".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/query-metrics-apache-spark-structured-streaming/read

This is an excellent site that addresses the aspects and more, passing the credit to this site therefore.

Comment: That helped a lot and solve all my issues. Thanks very much.

Comment: I have the same confusion even after going through the link you mentioned. I am reading data from Kafka and inside `foreachBatch` loop, I am just printing the count of micro batch. What I observe here is that for all micro batches, addBatch is either 0 or 1, whereas addBatch is in thousands (11516, 9244, 8626 etc)

So my question is why addBatch is just 0/1 ms as it should take some time to get data from Kafka which is not running on my local. I wonder if getBatch is either correct or its definition mentioned in above link is correct

Comment: one must make do  post a new question